# « Fournie », « donnée » ou « indiquée » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Quand vous passerez prendre mon véhicule, je ne me trouverai pas à l’adresse domiciliaire

…donnée à la signature du contrat (convention de vente). Un mandataire sera chargé de vous remettre les clefs.

…fournie à la signature du contrat (convention de vente). Un mandataire sera chargé de vous remettre les clefs.

…indiquée à la signature du contrat (convention de vente). Un mandataire sera chargé de vous remettre les clefs.

…indiquée dans la convention de vente lors de la signature/de sa signature/de la signature de celui-ci. Un mandataire sera chargé de vous remettre les clefs.

D’autres variantes à proposer ?

Comment: Une adresse n'est pas donnée au moment de la signature d'un contrat. L'adresse serait écrite dans le texte du contrat. Et puis, moi, je dirai: l'adresse de mon domicile.

Comment: Effectivement il aurait plutôt fallu que j’écrive « l’adresse de mon domicile que j’ai donnée à l’achat de mon véhicule »

Comment: Merci de votre reconnaissance, Thérèse.

Comment: "précisée dans le contrat", "inscrite dans le contrat", "mentionnée dans le contrat" ou encore "qui se trouve dans le contrat".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Lorsque vous prendrez possession de mon véhicule à l'adresse indiquée sur le contrat, je ne serai pas sur place. Un mandataire se chargera de vous remettre les clefs.